ConfigurationMetadata for Spring OAuth2Client ClientRegistration Class on ProviderDetails attribute
my OAuth provider requires a custom header like this: --header 'Authorization: Bearer ****'. I wanted to set the value for this header in my application.properties to maintain better organization, similar to how I set the token-uri. After researching the classes, I found that the ClientRegistration class contains the following attribute:
    public class ProviderDetails implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = SpringSecurityCoreVersion.SERIAL_VERSION_UID;

        private String authorizationUri;

        private String tokenUri;

        private UserInfoEndpoint userInfoEndpoint = new UserInfoEndpoint();

        private String jwkSetUri;

        private String issuerUri;

        private Map<String, Object> configurationMetadata = Collections.emptyMap();


so that you can set this values as follows on application.properties
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.example-provider.token-uri=https://example-token.com


Intuitively, I tried setting the value for configurationMetadata as follows, but it doesn't seem to work:
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.example-provider.configuration-metadata.key=value


I couldn't find any articles or examples regarding this, so if anyone could help me with this issue or at least explain the purpose of that attribute, I would appreciate it.
